# Validate Sign Up User data in serializers - Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have an issue with Validate Sign Up User data in serializers - Django Rest Framework. Hope your guys help me!

**My request:**

I want to create sign up form with user enter Duplicate email, it'll raise serializer object which duplicate.

**My serializers:**

```
class UserDuplicateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'full_name',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
        ]

class UserSignUpSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    username = CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'email',
            'password'
        ]
    extra_kwargs = {"password": {"write_only": True}}

    # Validate duplicate username
    def validate_username(self, value):
        data = self.get_initial()
        username = data.get("username")
        username_qs = User.objects.filter(username=username)
        if username_qs.exists():
            duplicate_obj = User.objects.get(username=username)
            serializer = UserDuplicateSerializer(duplicate_obj)
            raise ValidationError(format(serializer.data))
        else:
            pass
        return value

    def create(self, validated_data):
        username = validated_data['username']
        ...
        user_obj.save()
        return validated_data
```

**It renders:**

```
{'username': u'duongnuhabang', 'first_name': u'D\u01b0\u01a1ng N\u1eef', 'profile_pic_url': OrderedDict([('id', 71), ('image', '/media/users/2/13_71.jpg'), ('config_translateY', 0)]), 'last_name': u'H\u1ea1 B\u0103ng', 'full_name': u'D\u01b0\u01a1ng N\u1eef H\u1ea1 B\u0103ng'}
```

**But I want to JSON Type:**

```
{'username': 'duongnuhabang', 'first_name': 'Feed Git', ...}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
raise ValidationError("This username has been registered!" +str( serializer.data))
```

use this in your validation error

Comment: glad could help bro :)

Comment: Sorry. Your code have some problems. It renders `"{'username': u'feedgit', 'first_name': u'D\\u01b0\\u01a1ng N\\u1eef', 'profile_pic_url': OrderedDict([('id', 71), ('image', '/media/users/2/13_71.jpg'), ('config_translateY', 0)]), 'last_name': u'H\\u1ea1 B\\u0103ng', 'full_name': u'D\\u01b0\\u01a1ng N\\u1eef H\\u1ea1 B\\u0103ng'}"`. It's not JSON type.

Comment: where are you rendering the data?

Comment: Please view my photo above! I want to print object which duplicate with username!

Comment: you dont need to display serializer.data for that, you need serializer.errors in that place